# How to checkout part of local Subversion repository?

Tags: svn

Normally if you want checkout a specific directory within a SVN repository you can do:

```
svn co https://server/repos/path/in/repos
```

But how to do this with a local repository?

```
svn co file:///path/to/repos/path/in/repos
```

gives an error:

```
svn: URL 'file:///path/to/repos/path/in/repos' doesn't exist
```

which is true, the repository lives at: `file:///path/to/repos`.

How can I checkout a specific directory within a SVN repository using a local URI?

Comment: Subversion treats all protocols equally. If svn says the path doesn't exist, that's the most likely cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
z:\>dir /B
repo
```

checkout from `z:\repo` repository-trunk

```
z:\>svn co file:///Z:/repo/trunk
Checked out revision 1.
```

Check format of URI, and, after all, presence of required node inside repo with `svn ls URL`

Comment: It was indeed a typo :$